# Use a "ChatGPT like" engine really locally without exposing sensitive data

Tags: python, gpt, chatbot

I was recently playing around with `llama_index` and `llama Hub` and found it very easy to be used on my own data set.
While this is nice, I cannot expose sensitive data of my organization to external resources (such as OpenAI).

I read there's a new local port called GPT4All, but wasn't able to find how (if any) to introduce a new data into its model.

Can someone please recommend of a suitable alternative that can be used really locally?

Comment: introduce new data for domain fine-tuning, instruction fine-tuning or inference?

Comment: Not sure what is the difference so I'll put it in my own words: "I'd like to use my own dataset with the capabilities of ChatGPT".
e.g. creating a Slack bot that will be "trained" on the data discussed in my organization Slack channels

Answer (score 1):

See the [gpt4all issue #374, "How to train the model with my own files"](https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all/issues/374). [One comment there](https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all/issues/374#issuecomment-1510306081) says:

> My understanding is that embeddings and retraining (fine-tuning) are different. If you just want extra info, you can embed, if you want new knowledge or style, you probably need to fine-tune.

which cites: ["GPT4All Story, Fine-Tuning, Model Bias, Centralization Risks, AGI (Andriy Mulyar)", § "Fine Tuning Options" (@35:12)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZW1E017VEc&t=2112s).